# SQL Stuff Function with Variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-function

I am trying to generate an Pivot table with SQL (SQL Server 2008). To get the column list I am using stuff function which works great if we use it with SQL.

Although due to dynamic nature of Pivot structure (selection by user) I want to make column name set as a variable. I can catch correct SQL Stuff syntax but not able to execute it. Any Idea?

See code example as below:
**Working Code:**

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Station) 
                    from #ResultCrosstab
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
Select @cols
```

**Not Working Code as below**

```
Declare @ColumnName varchar(100)
set @ColumnName='Station'
DECLARE @cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @queryCol AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @queryCol='STUFF((SELECT distinct '','' + QUOTENAME(' + @ColumnName + ') 
                    from #ResultCrosstab
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') 
        ,1,1,'''')'

Select @queryCol
Select @cols1=(@queryCol)
```

*Not Working code returns the sql query itself rather than result.*

Any Idea or suggestions?

Cheers
Hardeep

Comment: I cant see where you are executing the query.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know why people frequently refer to this way of constructing a comma separated string of values as the/a `STUFF` method. Are you aware that all that `STUFF` is doing is trimming the leading `,` off of the text that `FOR XML PATH` is generating.

Comment: check this
 
[**Dynamic pivot query**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Or

[**Dynamic pivot multiple columns**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072744/sql-server-pivot-with-multiple-x-axis-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the query rather than select it.  `Select @queryCol` will return the value of `@queryCol`

`Select @cols1=(@queryCol)` will put the value of `@queryCol` into `@cols1`

You will need to `EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@queryCol)` or  `EXEC(@queryCol)` to execute the actual query